# Getting all the links in a webpage

Tags: python, hyperlink

Trying to extract all the links from a webpage, tried couple of codes. For example I have tried

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import lxml.html
connection = urlopen('http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central1.amazonaws.com/')

dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())

for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'): # select the url in href for all atags(links)
    print(link)
```

But though it works for other webpages, but it does not work for the webpage I want to extract. The webpage I am trying is
         Webpage='http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/'

Things I want to know: Is this website a special website? As far I know its a cloud storage of Amazon Web Service.

How can I do that for this site?
I am new in python and have a very little knowledge about it. Please pardon me for any mistakes in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually a Python question, it's an HTML question. The links on the that website are relative links. For instance, there is the link "#products/". When you click on it, your browser takes you to http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#products/ ; your browser knows to put the "http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/" part in the beginning because that's what website it's on. But when you extract the link, you're getting just the "#products/" part, and if you post that into the URL bar in a browser, it's not going to take you to the correct page because now your browser doesn't know what website the relative link is for. You'll need to keep track of a parent_url variable, and modify relative links to "{}relative_url".format(parent_url). You should also do a check to see whether there's a slash at the end of parent_url, and add one if there isn't.